# File.exists() returns false for existing file

Tags: android, file-exists

I am trying to check if a file exists in my user's Download directory.

```
File imageFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS),imageName);
if(imageFile.exists())
  // Do something
else
  // Do something else
```

I have gotten the contents of the directory

```
File did = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS));
File files[] = dir.listFiles();
```

In the debugger:

```
imageFile.path = "/storage/emulated/0/Download/floorplan_lobby.png"
```

And

```
files[12].path = "/storage/emulated/0/Download/floorplan_lobby.png"
```

But `imageFile.exists()` returns false. Why?

*It shouldn't matter, but I'm using a Samsung Galaxy Note.*

Comment: i used to access files like this `File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
    + "/Folder/Folder/Folder/file.jpg");`

Comment: How did that file supposedly get there?  Can a file manager app open it for viewing?  Perhaps the storage emulation is in an inconsistent state and needs to be refreshed by invoking the media scanner or rebooting the device.

Comment: The file was added using the Android File Transfer app.  The file manager can open the file.  I have rebooted the device.  No help.

Comment: It's 2 years later but did you ever get to the bottom of this?

Comment: Were you able to solve this?

Comment: @DanEckhart Have you check permission(WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)?

Answer (score 0):

**Check**

1. Manifest permissions

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

2. Use file provider to create and access file

```
    <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="your_package.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_list" />
        </provider>
```

3. file_list content:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <paths>
        <external-path
            name="external"
            path="." />
        <external-files-path
            name="external_files"
            path="." />
        <cache-path
            name="cache"
            path="." />
        <external-cache-path
            name="external_cache"
            path="." />
        <files-path
            name="files"
            path="." />
    </paths>
```

4. Keep your filename short